# How to Connect MS Access DB stored on SharePoint using Python

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access

How to connect a MS Access DB file stored on SharePoint using python and perform data operation. Have tried using pyodbc.connect and below is the connection string that i used but its not working.

Connection String:
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx/Shared%20Documents/General/test.accdb;', autocommit=True)

Comment: You cannot use URIs in the `DBQ` parameter, it has to be a local filesystem or network-share (UNC) path. Access cannot use database files accessed over HTTP (it really wouldn't work: think about how database engines need to take exclusive-locks on sections of a database file and require fast IO - you can't do that over normal HTTP).